# On page load function

Tags: jquery, resize, pageload

I'm using the following javascript in my html header to run some code when the browser window is resized:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    //run some javascript code here
});
```

My question is is there a way to modify the script to so that the code also runs when the page initially loads? or if the user refreshes the browser window.

Answer (score 3):

I use it quiet often in my applications, but i would put it like this.

```
function doLayout(){
 //run some javascript code here
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    doLayout();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    doLayout();
});
```

Comment: No need for a closure here :)

Comment: You are right Jan, but don't you ever get mixed up with functions and just variables that way?

Comment: Passing a regular variable here would trigger a error. If the variable contained a function then everything would be OK :)

Comment: I actually meant I can't keep track of what is a function or what is a variable in larger applications, in my case though:)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
function onResizeOrLoad () {
  // run some JS code here
}

$( window ).resize ( onResizeOrLoad );
$( document ).ready ( onResizeOrLoad );
```

This defines a function `onResizeOrLoad` that you then bind to two events: window resize and page load.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by two ways as shown below :

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    //run some javascript code here
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  //run some javascript code here
});
```

Or you can run have the common function to execute..

```
function executeCode() {
   // Javascript code here..
}

$(window).resize(executeCode);
$(document).ready(executeCode);
```

Comment: Revenge-downvoting other answers is a bit childish, isn't it?

Comment: I have downvoted you, because your solution does not provide an answer to the question.